Repository and information to pass to the view
I am implementing Repository.
I had a controller that used 'ViewData' to pass the user ID to my view.
Old ArticlesController.cs:
public IActionResult AjoutArticle()
{
    ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");

    return View();
}

With Repository, the controller no longer has access to the context that is in 'ArticlesRepository.cs' :
public void CreateArticle(Articles article)
{
    _context.Articles.Add(article);
}

New 'ArticlesController.cs':
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IArticlesRepository _repo;

    public ArticlesController(IArticlesRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id"); //<-- _context does not exist in the current context
        return View();
    }
}

I can't find how to pass the same information to my view.
Thanks

Please edit the post to include the defintion of IArticlesRepository.

I found a solution.
I had two lines to replace in my controller:
ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");
ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", article.ApplicationUserId);

So I created two methods in 'ArticlesRepository.cs':
        public SelectList  GetUser()
    {
        var idUser = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");

        return idUser;
    }
    public SelectList  GetUserWithArticle(Articles article)
    {
        var idUser = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", article.ApplicationUserId);

        return idUser;
    }

and, in 'IArticlesRepository.cs':
    SelectList GetUser();
    SelectList GetUserWithArticle(Articles article);

Which gives, in the new controller:
ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = _repo.GetUser();
ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = _repo.GetUserWithArticle(article);

It works.
Thanks!
